Implementación de atomic design en un proyecto de react
Estoy intentando realizar un proyecto en react usando atomic design, pero estoy teniendo muchas dudas si voy por un buen camino o puedo llegar a mejorar en algunos factores, como tal el proyecto es un tipo classroom , donde tendre un login, una vista principal, algunas cards , etc. En la siguiente imagen es como esta estructurado:

en la carpeta page tengo lo que serian las paginas totales de mi proyecto y mando a llamar a algunos organismos , como en la siguiente foto:

y como tal el proyecto se veria de esta manera

Quisiera saber si voy por un buen camino o en que podría mejorar.
Se que este tipo de pregunta no aporta mucho a la comunidad , pero si es posible me gustaría su orientacion, ya que aun soy nuevo en esto.
Anexo link de git en caso de que quieran verlo un poco mejor: https://github.com/JhairAlexby1/WALL-E.git


Te recomendaria ver esta imagen, respeta ese orden. No es un lugar donde preguntar por tu feedback, lo mas probable eliminen la publicacion. Aun asi, aqui tienes algun modelo a seguir, encontraras muchos mas si buscas en google o tu navegador "atom design", tendras muchos ejemplos y etc...
Empieza a utilizar diferentes herramientas para este tipo de consultas, ya sea google, chat gpt u otros medios. Alli podras conseguir buena orientacion.
Espero te sirva la foto, hasta donde veo es una buena forma de ir ordenando y armando tu proyecto si entiendes perfectamente la metodologia.
Saludos!.
